# ASP.Net Databound control not updating, possible cache issue?

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, browser-cache

Working on a project with a setup like this:

- ASPX Page

  - User Control 1

    - Radio Buttons 1-12
  - User Control 2

    - Labels of values calculated off of Radio Buttons 1-12

Both UserControls are Databound, both have a "SaveData" method called from the ASPX page.

The values in UserControl2 are in Labels.  The first is the number of the Radio button that was clicked (1 through 12), the 2nd is a value calculated based off that number.

When the page is Saved, the values are correctly saved and repopulated for the Radio Buttons.  The labels are still the old values when the UserControl repopulates.

If you then put the cursor in the address bar and refresh, you have the same issue.  But if you CTRL + Refresh, everything populates fine.

So obviously I've got an issue with the 2nd UserControl caching.  How can I get around this and why doesn't the first UserControl (with Radio Buttons) cache?

***EDIT***
While testing I added a TextBox bound to the same value as the RadioButton and the Label.  3 Controls, RadioButton using Bind on Field1, TextBox and Label using Eval on Field1 (but have tried Bind which also didn't work).
I changed the RadioButton from 1 to 3 and Saved.
On PostBack, RadioButton was correctly updated to 3.  TextBox and Label both still said "1".
I then changed the RadioButton to 6 and typed "4" in the TextBox (testing if a change in value would force update even though it was on EVAL, not BIND) and hit "Save".
On PostBack, RadioButton was correct at 6 but TextBox and Label both said "3".

No idea what that means, but someone might make sense of that.

Comment: Also, because I know the question will be asked, let's assume the structure of how this is set up cannot be changed.

Comment: Please post your code.  I don't think it's a caching issue.

Comment: For the control that works, there is too much code to post.  For the control that doesn't, there is nothing in the code behind.   Just an ObjectDataSource and Bind in the controls.

Comment: Is any Ajax involved i.e. UpdatePanel?

Comment: Are both user controls being populated at the same point in the page cycle? That wouldn't explain browser caching though. I'm not sure how that could happen unless you are actually modifying the response headers to do that.

Comment: Both controls are being populated by the built in DataBinding in .Net.  Calling FormView.DataBind on the second UserControl on Page Load doesn't even force it to rebind correctly.  
I can't think of a reason why one control would rebind and the other wouldn't.

Comment: Do you have a quick test sample that replicates this behavior? You don't have any caching on the UC itself right?

Comment: Trying to set up a test sample to replicate the behavior.  It's a big project with lots of dependencies.  I do not have any specific caching being done on the UserControl (or anything for that matter)

Comment: I can duplicate the issue with a brand new ASPX page that has nothing but these 2 UserControls and a Save button.

Comment: As I said, a simplest possible sample that replicates your issue will help us investigate the issue (DB not required but just a comment about where DB is used would do). From the flow you mentioned, I was wondering if the Second control is fetching values from DB before the RB selection is updated.

Comment: The simplest example I can think of is this:  Make 2 UserControls, one with a RadioButtonList bound to "Field1" (using EntityFramework), the other UserControl gets a single Label bound to "Field1".  Make an ASPX page with those 2 UserControls and a Save button.  The Save button calls "Form.UpdateItem" on each of the UserControls.  Calling "Form.DataBind" on the 2nd UserControl's "SaveData" method doesn't fix the issue either.

Comment: Correction!  Calling UserControl2's "Form.DataBind" on "SaveData" method DOES fix the issue.  I was looking at the wrong browser window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue comes down to the fact that the Button Click to call the "SaveData" methods on the 2 User Controls occurs AFTER the DataBinding.  Calling "Form.DataBind" on the 2nd UserControl inside the "Save Data" method (or any time after the first UserControl has saved) fixes the issue.